# Is it possible to create a type where we can type the second argument based on the type of the first argument?

Tags: typescript, generics

The type of the first argument defines the type of the second argument. I'd rather not have it as a type argument but rather as a generic function type so that it's inferred and doesn't need to be passed

I like to type the following function:

```js
const addT = (a, b) => a + b
```

- `a` can be `string | number`
- `b` should be the same as `typeof a`

There are a few variants that can be thought of, but none of them are inferring from the arguments' type.

```js
const addT = <T extends string | number>(a, b) => a + b
//                                                ^^^^^
// Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.(2365)


addT(1,3)
addT("","")
```

```js
type TAdd2 = {
  // overload for when both a and b are numbers
  <T extends number>(a: T, b: T): T;
  // overload for when both a and b are strings
  <T extends string>(a: T, b: T): T;
};

const add: TAdd2 = (a, b) => a + b;
//                  ^  ^
// Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)
// Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7006)

add("", "")
add(1, 2)
```

```js
// This doesn't work because TAdd3 is now defaulting the generic type argument to `string`

type TAdd3<T1 extends string | number = string, T2 extends string | number = string> = (a: T1, b: T2) => (T1 extends number ? (T2 extends number ? number : never) : string);
const add3: TAdd3 = (a, b) => a + b;
add3("", "")
add3(1,2)
//   ^
// Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)
```

```js
const add4 = <T extends number | string>(a: T) => (b: T) => typeof a === 'string' ?  a + b : `${a}${b}`;
add4(1)(3)
//      ^
// Argument of type '3' is not assignable to parameter of type '1'.(2345)
```

[Playground link for the examples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#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)

Comment: https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-type-guards/

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar issues before. The problem with trying to do it with generics is:

- T extends number does not necessarily mean T is any number. It could mean that T is 3 e.g. `add<3>(3,3)` and then 3+3 is not 3 so the result is not T anymore.
- T extends string | number is true when you do `add<3|'a'>(3, 'a')` but in this case the result is (after coercion) the string `'3a'` which again is not T

The closest I have come to ever solving it was:

```
function add(a: string, b: string): string;
function add(a: number, b: number): number;
function add(a: any, b: any) {  
  return a+b;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwCaoBTIFyIM5QBOMYA5gDSIBGuBxZAlLUSaQNwBQoksCK6WXGBABbKgFNClGomFjJTWaImFO3aPCRpMOFGACe03MgMNEAb0SIOVwuKghCWgNRVOAXw4cICAojt4iAC8-JgARGGUEQycVnGIAPQJAHoA-N6%20UP7ieABMwaEYAIyUuQw28Ykp6V5AA)

The `any` there is to just get the function to work. TS will deduce which overload was called based on the parameters. As far as I can tell you can only call using the first 2 signatures, calling it with anything else should error.

Comment: So the problem isn't with the generics, it's with the fact that `string | number` as a type doesn't mean "either a string or a number", it means "the union of the set of all strings and the set of all numbers". The difference is subtle but in this case, crucial.